# Dragleave is not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, drag

I created a little [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0ksbt1vs/2/) in JSFiddle testing drag events in IE.

In IE11 (haven't tested in older versions), if I drag the `div` into the `span`, `dragenter` fires, but not `dragleave` (more specifically, the `dragleave` handler isn't called). Why is this?

In Chrome, both events fire as expected.

**Bonus fiddle:**

I see the same issue when I put two divs next to each other. https://jsfiddle.net/1m0gbL4d/4/

**Update:** Likely, this is an IE bug.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p9L3bvd7/ that I've created based on code here: http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/ for eventSupport detection on browser. Strange that IE does support 'dragleave' event but doesn't fire the event.
Just a suggestion: add attributes `draggable="true"` to the divs. It makes them draggable without need for double click.

Comment: Seems like this code from msdn works on IE. dragleave is fired
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/DragDropEventsEX.htm

Comment: I reached a point where just the width being set is making whole difference. Checkout these 2 fiddles: https://jsfiddle.net/f3ap2242/3/ https://jsfiddle.net/fb5sp5yc/1/ . Both differ only in width property. But different behavior. One fires dragLeave, other doesn't. Strange.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Interesting. Notice if you explicitly set the width to 100% (what is was before, but now we're being explicit), it works. The moment we remove the width property from #d, it breaks.